# No FileSystem for scheme: sftp

Tags: hadoop, sftp, distcp

I am trying to use sftp in hadoop with distcp like below

```html
hadoop distcp -D fs.sftp.credfile=/home/bigsql/cred.prop sftp://<<ip address>>:22/export/home/nz/samplefile hdfs:///user/bigsql/distcp
```

But I am getting the below error

```html
15/11/23 13:29:06 INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false, syncFolder=false, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=false, maxMaps=20, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[sftp://<<source ip>>:22/export/home/nz/samplefile], targetPath=hdfs:/user/bigsql/distcp, targetPathExists=true, preserveRawXattrs=false}
15/11/23 13:29:09 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://bigdata.ibm.com:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
15/11/23 13:29:09 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at bigdata.ibm.com/<<target ip>>:8050
15/11/23 13:29:10 ERROR tools.DistCp: Exception encountered
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: sftp
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.GlobbedCopyListing.doBuildListing(GlobbedCopyListing.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.buildListing(CopyListing.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createInputFileListing(DistCp.java:353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.execute(DistCp.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:401)
```

Can anyone suggest what can be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Do you have a jar file implementing "sftp" file system? It is complaining that, it is not finding any file system with name "sftp". By default, "hdfs" is the file system.

Comment: What is the default jar I should be looking for and in which location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is coming, because Hadoop is not able to find a file system implementation for the scheme: `sftp`.

The exception occurs in `FileSystem.java`. The framework tries to find the value for configuration parameter `fs.sftp.impl` and when it does not find it, it throws this exception.

As far as I know, Hadoop does not support `sftp` file system by default. This JIRA ticket [Add SFTP FileSystem][https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5732], indicates that, SFTP is available from Hadoop version 2.8.0.

To fix this, you need to do 2 things:

1. Add a jar containing `sftp` file system implementation to your HADOOP deployment.
2. Set the config parameter: `fs.sftp.impl` to a fully qualified class name of the `sftp` implementation.

I came across this git repository, which contains `sftp` implementation for Hadoop: https://github.com/wnagele/hadoop-filesystem-sftp. To use this, you need to set property `fs.sftp.impl` to `org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem`.

Comment: I have identified the jar and it is an IBM jar file (as I am using IBM BigInsights), I have added the below in the core-site.xml file `<property>
    <name>fs.sftp.impl</name>
    <value>com.ibm.biginsights.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem</value>
  </property>` But I am getting the error as : `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem not found`

Comment: I have also extracted the jar into class file and found the path is coming as `com\ibm\biginsights\hadoop\fs\sftp\SFTPFileSystem`

Comment: Have you ensured that, this jar is present in the HADOOP path? It should be present in one of the Hadoop paths: %HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/, %HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/. I am also  using a custom file system and it works fine for me.

Comment: Now I am getting error like `15/11/30 12:32:40 ERROR tools.DistCp: Exception encountered
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No user specified for sftp connection. Expand URI or credential file.
        at com.ibm.biginsights.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem$ConfWrapper.readConnectionValues(Unknown Source)`

Comment: This means, Hadoop is now recognizing SFTP file system. Now, there is a problem with your credentials. Did you check if your credentials file at: "/home/bigsql/cred.prop" is correct?

Comment: username and password is fine as I am able to ssh using that username and password in that other box...I have specified the credential as `username=nz
password=***********`

Comment: I hope you went through this: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.dev.doc/doc/c_sample_apps_distcopy.html . It has explanation about supplying credentials to SFTP, through different ways.

Comment: strange thing observed, when executing the below it is not throwing error `hadoop distcp sftp://user:password@<<ip_address>>:<<port>>/export/home/nz/samplefile hdfs:///user/bigsql/distcp` but throwing error when executing below `hadoop distcp -D fs.sftp.credfile=/home/bigsql/cred.prop sftp://<<ip_address>>:<<port>>/export/home/nz/samplefile hdfs:///user/bigsql/distcp` but /home/bigsql/cred.prop is having the correct user-id and password in the form `username=nz password=***********`

Comment: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.dev.doc/doc/c_sample_apps_distcopy.html This link has a sample credential file

Comment: This finally works when I placed the credential file in HDFS.