# Google Cloud Dataproc OOM issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I run into OOM issue, when execute a code on Spark cluster (Dataproc).

Environment: 
2-node cluster, each node has 6G of memory.
Test file size is 20Gb.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import pyspark

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.sftp.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem')

data = sc.textFile("sftp://user:pass@54.23.12.100/data/tmp/test_tile.csv.gz")
data.saveAsTextFile("gs://data/tmp")
```

Is it possible to stream data into GCS using Spark cluster and have a throttling (buffer) for worker nodes to avoid OOM error? Or if there's some other solution to read data from external source (sftp) and persist it into GCS?

Comment: What version of dataproc do you run your pyspark?

Answer (score 4):

It will be more appropriate to use Hadoop [DistCp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) instead of Spark to copy file from SFTP server to GCS.

Here is an instruction on how to configure SFTP support in Hadoop:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878054/3227693.

Answer (score 3):

For external solution you can try [rclone](https://github.com/ncw/rclone), which can sync data from sftp to GCS. Or just download from sftp , and use gstuil copy to GCS.

It's better idea from spark read data direct from gcs.

You you still want to read file from sftp in Spark, you may wnat to try this one
[Spark SFTP Connector Library](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp)