# CDAP Source plugin to read data from Sftp server

Tags: hadoop, cdap

I want to read a csv file that is available to Sftp server by using a cdap source plugin.

I came across [FTP Batch Source](https://github.com/cdapio/hydrator-plugins/blob/release/2.3/core-plugins/docs/FTP-batchsource.md) plugin that does the same. But when running this i am getting below exception.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: sftp
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2798) ~[org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2809) ~[org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100) ~[org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2848) ~[org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2830) ~[org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389) ~[org.apache.hadoop.hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at co.cask.hydrator.format.plugin.AbstractFileSource.prepareRun(AbstractFileSource.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.hydrator.format.plugin.AbstractFileSource.prepareRun(AbstractFileSource.java:63) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource$1.call(WrappedBatchSource.java:53) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource$1.call(WrappedBatchSource.java:50) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.Caller$1.call(Caller.java:30) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.StageLoggingCaller.call(StageLoggingCaller.java:40) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSource.java:50) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSource.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource$1.call(WrappedBatchSource.java:53) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource$1.call(WrappedBatchSource.java:50) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.Caller$1.call(Caller.java:30) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.StageLoggingCaller.call(StageLoggingCaller.java:40) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSource.java:50) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSource.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSource.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.etl.common.submit.SubmitterPlugin$3.run(SubmitterPlugin.java:83) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext$2.run(AbstractContext.java:534) ~[na:na]
    at co.cask.cdap.data2.transaction.Transactions$CacheBasedTransactional.finishExecute(Transactions.java:224) ~[na:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

I am using below version of libraries which is also a ristriction.

1. `Hadoop - 2.7.3`
2. `Spark - 2.3.0`

I also came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878054/4652875) question which suggest using [this](https://github.com/wnagele/hadoop-filesystem-sftp) and setting proeprty `fs.sftp.impl` to `org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem` will solve the issue but not sure how use above code and set this proeprty.

Comment: Instead of just adding the proeprty `{
  "fs.sftp.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem"
}` i used `SFTPFileSystem` class to make connection and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a file system properties under the Advanced section when using SFTP as the protocol:

```
{
  "fs.sftp.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem"
}
```

Comment: I have already added that property. I tried making my own sftp connection and it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP plugin is deprecated to my understanding. Use the SFTP Action plugin instead and build a pipeline like so :

[image]

The idea is to first copy the file to the local file system of the runtime environment and then sink the file where you wish (GCS in my case).